# Nexus 7: Assert failed: device == grouper when trying to install some roms

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, nexus-7, twrp

So I have Nexus 7 (not the 2013 one), Wi-Fi version, with TWRP recovery, version 2.6.3.1 installed.

When trying to install some roms, for example, SmoothRom, or PAC, installation fails with following message:

```
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "grouper" || getprop ("ro.build.product") == "grouper"
```

the problem is, I'm 100% sure nexus 7 wi-fi is grouper. 
Some other roms, like cyanogenmod install OK, but I'd like to try something else.

So, what's the problem, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly I had this exact same problem.

It seems to be an issue with the latest version of TWRP. I solved it by downgrading TWRP to **2.6.3.0** - I'm assuming there must be a bug with the 2.6.3.1 version.

That *should* work (as my scenario was the same: Nexus 7 (1), TWRP and the MIUI ROM).